# Error connecting databricks while using sql.connect from Spyder (Windows)

Tags: python, databricks

I am trying to connect databricks from my local python/spyder on my windows machine:

```
from databricks import sql
import os

connection = sql.connect(
   server_hostname = os.getenv("DATABRICKS_SERVER_HOSTNAME"),
   http_path       = os.getenv("DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH"),
   access_token    = os.getenv("DATABRICKS_TOKEN"))
```

However, it gives me the following error:

> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))

Any help would be appreciated!

I want to have a successful connection to adls gen2 db using sql.connect